# pymc - after running the model, priors are outside their support?

Tags: pymc

I have been observing some strange behavior in pymc which I hopelessly trying to understand.
In my mcmc model I define several variables to be uniform between [0.,1.], i.e.

```
beta = Uniform('beta', 0., 1., value=0.2)
```

And after sampling the model, I sometimes get weird values for those variables

```
>>> beta.value
array(10.860185597232812)
```

Needless to say that beta is outside its support and even pymc knows that's the case

```
>>>beta.get_logp()
ZeroProbability                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-f289ec6ca008> in <module>()
----> 1 beta.get_logp()

/Users/rouli/envs/env0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/PyMCObjects.pyc in get_logp(self)
    927                     (self._value, self._parents.value))
    928             else:
--> 929                 raise ZeroProbability(self.errmsg)
    930 
    931         return logp

ZeroProbability: Stochastic beta's value is outside its support,
 or it forbids its parents' current values.
```

So what happens? Is that a bug in pymc (2.3.3) or in my understanding?

Full code - https://gist.github.com/rouli/1ed077f5aa64a4720857

Comment: So odd. Can you post the model? My first guess is that beta is being overwritten somehow.

Comment: Thanks! - here's a simplified model that recreates that problem for me (sort of a SIR model) - https://gist.github.com/rouli/1ed077f5aa64a4720857
Surely, I misunderstand something :(

Comment: I'm not hitting the bug unfortunately - I'm using PyMC 2.3 fyi

Comment: Are you running this from the ipython console, or as a script?

Comment: ipython notebook. 
we did discover that setting Metropolis as the step function, i.e.
mc.use_step_method(pymc.Metropolis, xbeta, proposal_distribution='Prior')
solves that problem. So probably some bug in the library itself.

Comment: I've seen similar behavior with Uniform priors - the upper bound appears to be completely ignored.